# Public key login to computer with very old openSSH

Tags: linux, security, login, openssh, public-key

I use ssh public key to login to a very old Linux machine running OpenSSH 5.9p1, and it's all worked fine for the past decade. Recently, though, I updated my work machine's OS (which is now running OpenSSH 9.0), and now public key login fails with a `send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm` error. I can get in with the password, but I need public key authentication to work. How can I persuade the two OpenSSHs to play nicely?

The details:

I can reconfigure either box's OpenSSH, and create and add keys, but I can't update either version of OpenSSH. The old Linux machine's security is relatively unimportant, and I have remote ssh into my work machine disabled (it's my laptop).

Here's the output from `nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -sV -p 22 WW.XX.YY.ZZ` for both my own machine and the Linux box. Lines that are present in both are marked with `(*)`. First my work machine:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 9.0 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh2-enum-algos: 
|   kex_algorithms: (10)
|       curve25519-sha256
|       curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
|       diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 (*)
|       diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
|       diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
|       diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp256
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp384
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp521
|       sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
|   server_host_key_algorithms: (4)
|       ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
|       rsa-sha2-256
|       rsa-sha2-512
|       ssh-ed25519
|   encryption_algorithms: (6)
|       aes128-ctr (*)
|       aes128-gcm@openssh.com
|       aes192-ctr (*)
|       aes256-ctr (*)
|       aes256-gcm@openssh.com
|       chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
|   mac_algorithms: (10)
|       hmac-sha1 (*)
|       hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha2-256 (*)
|       hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha2-512 (*)
|       hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
|       umac-64-etm@openssh.com
|       umac-64@openssh.com (*)
|       umac-128-etm@openssh.com
|       umac-128@openssh.com
|   compression_algorithms: (2)
|       none (*)
|_      zlib@openssh.com (*)
```

Now the Linux box:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 5.9p1 (protocol 2.0; HPN-SSH patch 13v11)
| ssh2-enum-algos: 
|   kex_algorithms: (4)
|       diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
|       diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 (*)
|       diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
|       diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
|   server_host_key_algorithms: (2)
|       ssh-dss
|       ssh-rsa
|   encryption_algorithms: (13)
|       3des-cbc
|       aes128-cbc
|       aes128-ctr (*)
|       aes192-cbc
|       aes192-ctr (*)
|       aes256-cbc
|       aes256-ctr (*)
|       arcfour
|       arcfour128
|       arcfour256
|       blowfish-cbc
|       cast128-cbc
|       rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
|   mac_algorithms: (11)
|       hmac-md5
|       hmac-md5-96
|       hmac-ripemd160
|       hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha1 (*)
|       hmac-sha1-96
|       hmac-sha2-256 (*)
|       hmac-sha2-256-96
|       hmac-sha2-512 (*)
|       hmac-sha2-512-96
|       umac-64@openssh.com (*)
|   compression_algorithms: (2)
|       none (*)
|_      zlib@openssh.com (*)
```

Suggestions? (Thanks.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current OpenSSH requires RSA-key authentication to be done using SHA2-based signatures, while your server only supports SHA1 per original specification. (The "ssh-rsa" key format is still the same but modern clients and servers additionally negotiate RSA signature modes as a separate step.)

For now, OpenSSH still has RSA-SHA1 support present but disabled by default; you can enable it on the client machine with the `ssh -o` or `.ssh/config` option:

```
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

In most cases you will also need the client to accept RSA-SHA1 signatures *from* the server when its hostkey is being validated:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

If you want, you can restrict these less-secure options to a specific set of machines by adding the following to your client's .ssh/config:

```
Host 10.3.4.*
     PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
     HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

For even older systems, use PuTTY – its `plink` CLI SSH client can connect to just about anything.

Comment: Most excellent: that worked. I've added an edit clarifying that these configurations are on the ssh client machine, not the host.

Comment: I've also added a note about restricting these options to specific hosts.